# Why has China's integration into the global economy caused it to slow it's output?

Tags: international-trade, nonexpert, china

In the following passage, what does it mean to be *integrated* into the economy and why does this mean that now China and India are *integrated* into the economy that their *output* has slowed down?

> In the 1990s and early 200s, global commerce was growing at twice the
> rate of output because big economies such as China, India and in
> eastern Europe were being integrated into the global economy. Now they
> have been more or less absorbed, it is only natural that things slow
> down, but this does not mean we have reached the high-water mark, says
> Okonjo-Iweala.

Ref: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.ft.com/content/87cb4674-6db7-41cf-a82e-44b83eaa436c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being integrated into the global economy means that country increases its trade openness and lifts restrictions on capital flows (you can look at [this](https://www.sesric.org/files/article/94.pdf) paper).

The article does not say that China's output slowed down. It says its rate of growth slowed down. Usually, a country that used to be closed and did not trade much before experiences a boost in the rate of economic growth. This is because trading allows the country to specialize in a good where the country has a comparative advantage. This boosts growth by a lot at the beginning but the effect eventually wears down as the country gets fully specialized and all low hanging fruit was already picked.